# Android AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.constraint.BuildConfig","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Tags: android, firebase

**its my gradle**
I had this problem on my project. Please help me

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.1'
implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'

implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I implemented off your gradles into my .app gradle file and didn't get any errors....